# Retrieve all fields from Rally WSAPI Recycle bin

Tags: sdk, rally, appsdk2, recycle-bin, wsapi

I am trying to list all the fields of the userstory in Recycle bin and I see only few. Can't all the fields be fetched?

```
            var config = {
                model: 'RecycleBinEntry',
                filters: [{
                    property: "ID",
                    operator: "=",
                    value: "US060000"
                }],
                fetch: ["Name","c_field"],
                context:{
                        workspace: me.getContext().getWorkspace()._ref,
                        project: null
                } 
            };
```

I don't get back my custom field(c_field) on the userstory. Can't you fetch all the fields of the User Story Model? I tried to get it from lookback and the value of the custom field is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is only a very small subset of the available artifact fields exposed on deleted items (RecycleBinEntry).